# Pipeline using CountVectorizer (max_df) before tfidf

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, countvectorizer

Currently i am not sure if this quation is for stackoverflow or another more theoretical statistical QA. But im confused about the following.

I am doing a binairy tekst classification task. For this task i use a pipeline, one of the example codes is below:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
('vect', CountVectorizer()),
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
('clf', LogisticRegression())
])

parameters = {
    'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],  
    'vect__stop_words': [None, stopwords.words('dutch'), stopwordList],
    'clf__C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
}
```

So nothing really strange about this,  but then i started playing with the parameter options/settings and noted that the code below (so the steps and parameters in the code) had the highest accuracy score (f1 score):

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
    ])

parameters = {
    'vect__ngram_range': [(1,1)],  
    'vect__stop_words': [None],
    'vect__max_df': [0.2], 
    'vect__max_features': [10000],
    'clf__C': [100]
}
```

So im pleased to sort of find out with which parameter settings and methods i get the highest score, but i cant figure out the exact meaning. As with the 'vectorizor'-step the settings for max_df (ignoring terms that appear in more 20% of the documents) seems to be strange to apply before tfidf (or somehow double)

Furthermore it also uses max_features of 10.000. What step is used before the max_df or the max_features? and how do i interpret max_features setting this parameter and doing tfidf afterwards. Does it then perform a tfidf over the 10.000 features?

For me it seems rather strange to do a tfidf after using parameters such as max_df and max_features? Am i correct? and why? or should i just do what gives the highest outcome..

I hope someone can help me in the right direction, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is the accuracy you found out, calculated on a single train test set, or by cross-validation?

Comment: Cross-validation as i am using gridsearch.